# CMake generate only one file during generate phase

Tags: cmake

Anyone know how to generate a file in cmake during the generate phase but only one file not one file per config?

I am using configure_file to generate a file that includes generator expressions and then using file(GENERATE ...) to take that file and create the final file, but file(GENERATE ...) runs for every config. I limited it to running only on debug config using `CONDITION $<CONFIG:Debug>` but I want it to run even if the debug config is not currently a config (but again I only need 1 file for all configs)

Comment: Can you explain why you need the file to be created at generate time, but not reflect any potentially per-config content?

Comment: building VS .user file, need targets directory location via `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${target}>` but the .user file is for all configs like most VS stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you craft your `INPUT` such that it is guaranteed to result in the same output for all configurations, you should be able to provide a configuration-independent name as the `OUTPUT` parameter of `file(GENERATE)` and thus end up with only one file.

Comment: yes I had that originally but the wording on cmake documentation "A specific OUTPUT file may be named by at most one invocation of file(GENERATE)" implies that that is not correct and maybe a bug in the current implementation.

Comment: @Krazer No, you're misreading that. Read the description of `OUTPUT`: " Multiple configurations may generate the same output file only if the generated content is identical." What you quoted says that two *different* `file(GENERATE)` commands may not point to the same output file.

Comment: I would like to add for anyone in a similar situation, you can generate one file with different config information. It requires recursively calling file(GENERATE... and packing some information in a target property. An example can be seen here: https://github.com/caseymcc/CreateLaunchers/blob/18d3e177b7f384c39c04d30b11be29d99c0ccaf5/cmake/CreateLaunchers.cmake#L224